# 'Used to' and 'Would' as 'describing habitual events and repeated actions in the past' but in Past Perfect

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, used-to

If I want to say that I used to something before the past I will mention further in the context, can I use past perfect in this case?

For instance:

> There **had been** days when the game **had been** quite popular, and those days I **had used to** play it a lot.

And in the next sentence I want to use 'would' (is it correct to use it in past perfect?). So, the next sentence:

> I **would have** played the game with my friend through the LAN network.

And now I'm telling that happened after the past I mentioned above:

> After that, I **used to** play another game.

And then I'm saying something about nowadays.

So, is it possible to say this way?

Comment: The context is not really clear. For the second sentence "would have" can imply "but didn't" or it can imply you don't actually remember.

Comment: It's a kind of replacement. "used to" can be replaced with "would" describing repeated actions in the past, yet here I'm trying to replace "had used to" with "would have", and I don't know if it's correct, that's the question actually. (and whether there's "had used to" at all or not) @Peter

Comment: Are you describing this as your personal history?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I'm talking about myself in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "had played" is appropriate when the statement is in the past, made from a point of view that is also in the past. If you are just recounting a sequence of past events viewed from the present, you don't use that construction. So your first sentence might become

> There was a time when the game was quite popular, and at that time (or back then) I used to play it a lot.

The next sentence would become

> I would play the game with my friend through the LAN network.

Using "after that" in the next sentence makes it sound like it happened later in the same day. To talk about the more recent past you could use something like

> More recently I used to play another game.

I also suggest you don't talk about days in the first sentence. Your construction sounds as though the game was popular for some days mixed in with days when it was not popular.